# How does $\int_0^1 e^{-u} \log(u)^2 \,du$ lead to hypergeometic function

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

$\int_0^1 e^{-u} \log(u)^2 du $ evaluates to the generalized hypergeometic function via Wolfram Alpha. Any idea how to obtain that as using $\frac{d}{da} x^a \rvert_{a = 0 } $ does not work due to the square.

With the hint the integral is the same as
$\frac{d^2}{da^2} \int_{0}^{1} e^{-u} u^{a}du = \underbrace{\Gamma''(1)}_{\gamma²+ \frac{\pi²}{6}} - \Gamma''(1,1)$
The minuend results in the Meijer G-function, how does this come?

Comment: If you mean $\log^{2}(u)$ then you just need to take 2nd derivative of $u^a$ w.r.t $a$ then you get $\log^{2}(u)$. Btw, you missed $du$.

Comment: Thanks, I included that, are there any known constant for $\Gamma''(1) - \Gamma''(1,1)$?

Comment: I found this for the first part, but how does it lead to the generalized hypergeometric function? https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-find-the-nth-derivative-of-the-gamma-function-at-z-1

Comment: Hint: For your original question, replace $e^{-u}$ with its [Maclaurin series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by Steven.

Use
$$
\int_0^1 u^n\big(\log u\big)^2\;du = \frac{2}{(n+1)^3},\qquad n \in \mathbb N.
$$
We get
$$
\int_0^1e^{-u}\big(\log u\big)^2\;du
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\int_0^1 u^n\big(\log u\big)^2\;du
\\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(-1)^n}{(n+1)^3 n!}
= 2\;{}_3 F_3\big(1,1,1;2,2,2;-1\big) .
$$