# $\int_N^{\infty} e^{-u} \log^2(u) du $ with variable start $N$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4786750/how-does-int-01-e-u-logu2-du-lead-to-hypergeometic-function) question the integral is solved for a constant lower integral limit. I want to determine the integral for a variable lower limit $N$ in terms of $N$.
$$\int_N^{\infty} e^{-u} \log^2(u) du = 
\frac{d^2}{da^2} \int_N^{\infty} e^{-u} u^a du = \Gamma''(1,N) $$
Now I don't know how to obtain an explicit expression in terms of $N$ of $\Gamma''(1,N)$. Using partial integration for $\int \log^2(u) u^n$ as in the previous question leads to a very complicated series. Yet, I want to understand how the integral behaves in terms of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in the **asymptotics** of the integral as $N\to\infty$ you can in fact derive a complete asymptotic series by successive integrations by parts. It is simple to show that the full asymptotic series can be written as

$$\int_N^ \infty e^{-u}\log^2 u~du\sim e^{-N}\log N\left(\log N+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{N^k}\right)+e^{-N}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{b_k}{N^k}\right)$$

with coefficients given by the following explicit formulas

$$a_m=2(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!$$$$b_m=a_m H_{m-1}$$

Here $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number, with the convention $H_0=0$. The series obviously doesn't converge for any non-zero value of $1/N$, but it is Borel resummable so it is unique.

If you are instead interested in a **convergent series** expansion, one can employ the following trick. First show that

$$\int_0^N e^{-u}\log^2 u~du=(1-e^{-N})\log^2N-2\log N\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n N^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+1)!}+2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n N^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2(n+1)!}$$

Then show the classic integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log^2 x dx=\gamma^2+\pi^2/6$ and the convergent series for the integral in question is just the difference of the two results;

$$\int_N^ \infty e^{-u}\log^2 u~du=\gamma^2+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-(1-e^{-N})\log^2N+2\log N\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n N^{n+1}}{(n+1)(n+1)!}-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n N^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2(n+1)!}$$

This series converges for any choice of $N$. However, it does not provide the correct value for the limit $N\to\infty$ as it stands. The two series in the last equation can be evaluated individually in terms of exponential integrals and hypergeometric functions, but I doubt a form like that is of direct value.

Comment: It seems that the Borel transforms have singularities on the principal sheet only at $-1$. Hence, you can also try a convergent factorial series in terms of $\frac{1}{N(N+1)\cdots(N+m)}$.

Comment: Is there a claim that allows a convergent series of that sort around $N= \infty$ to exist?

Comment: You may start on page 33 of this book: https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/19569 See also http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.2263.pdf (in French)

Comment: Hi, I know how to obtain the convergent series by using the Taylor expansion of the exponential function and integration by parts. I am also not sure how you obtained the asymptotic series. Did you start looking at the convergent series and then use the limit? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: And as they converge, how do $\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{N^k}$ and $\sum_{k =0}^{\infty} \frac{b_k}{N^k}$ scale in terms of $N$?

Comment: @Gary concerning using factorial series for the exact result, how to you obtain terms of the form $\frac{1}{N(N+1)\cdot\cdot\cdot (N+m)}$? $N$ in the nominator is not factorial?

Comment: You can obtain the asymptotic series by integrating by parts, always by writing the $e^{-u}=-(e^{-u})'$. It takes some effort to prove that the coefficients have this form but I think you could do it with induction fairly easily.

Comment: @user18722294 Alternatively, by letting $u=N(1+t)$, $$
\int_N^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - u} \log ^2 (u){\rm d}u}  = {\rm e}^{ - N} \log N\left( {\log N + 2N\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - Nt} \log (1 + t){\rm d}t} } \right) \\+ {\rm e}^{ - N} N\int_0^{ + \infty } {{\rm e}^{ - Nt} \log ^2 (1 + t){\rm d}t} .
$$ Now just apply Watson's lemma to the integrals. Since $\log$ and $\log^2$ are analytic for $\operatorname{Re}(t)>-1$, the factorial series follow from the general theory given in the book I linked above.

Comment: @Gary the integrals you derived are almost the Laplace transforms of $\log$ and $\log^2$ if there wouln't be the $+1$. For the Laplace transform there is a closed formula.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg I do not understand how it can be that the convergent series is not providing the right limit for $N \to \infty$

Comment: and if $N$ is very large the asymptotic should converge, only if N is very small it can be non-converging, right?

Comment: @user18722294 Asymptotic series like the one I wrote above do not converge for any value of $N$ except $N=\infty$, due to the fact that the coefficients grow fast, as fast or faster than factorial. If you do a simple convergence test, you'll see that the series diverges. The convergent series as written, does not provide a value for the large $N$ limit of the series. Of course there are other ways to show that the limit is zero, just not via the infinite series representation centered around $N=0$.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg what would be a working way to show that the limit is zero?

Comment: The asymptotic series (obviously)!! It's an expansion around $N=\infty$ so it gives the correct values for the limits of polynomial approximants as $N\to\infty $ much like the Taylor series does. There are other more direct ways as well that use the definition of the integral.

Comment: @DinosaurEgg could you elaborate on how the definition of the integral can be used to see that the limit is zero?

Comment: You can ask a different question for that, even though it should be relatively straight forward to see from my answer here.